# Get Reference in CodeBehind to ChangeContentType Control

Tags: content-type, custom-form

I am trying to get a reference to the  control in Edit/New mode in order to remove several of the Content Types in the DropDownList that is rendered during the PageLoad or Init phase.

I can't use JavaScript/jQuery to remove the items because I will get a ViewState exception.

I have already tried using Page.FindControl() but it returns null.

Any ideas?

Comment: the FindControl is not recursive so maybe you cannot find the Control because you are inside a iframe or some other strange HTML tag

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually figured it out. See answer below. Now I just need to figure out how to manipulate the list of Content Types that appear in the DropDownList.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. All I had to do was use the name of the ID (duh!). I thought that I would have to use like FindControl but as it turns out it's just as simple as using "ChangeContentType".